# How do I instal Skype on iMac G5 Ubuntu 12.04.1?

Tags: skype

So I have this imac G5 model 8.7 running powerpc64.

I can't install any of the `.debs` they have on skype.com because they're the wrong architecture and I also tried adding the partner repo for the software center but when I do `sudo apt-get install skype` it says it can't find the package as if the repo I just added doesn't exist. I added the repo with the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

I'm running

> Ubuntu Release 12.04 (precise) 32-bit
>  Kernel Linux
>   3.2.0-31-powerpc64-smp
>  GNOME 3.4.2

Comment: The funny thing is that after I added the repo with that command I wasn't asked to confirm adding it and neither did I see an RSA key being added as I do with other repos.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install skype`

Comment: there is a powerpc version of skype, a while back i downloaded it and installed it. don't know where i downloaded it try  http://www.skype.com/ and under the download section i think there is a powerpc download link. if not https://www.google.com/ ;)

Comment: I forgot to mention I already did run apt-get update

Comment: It's not just a normal powerpc version that I'm looking for, it's a powerpc version that will work under Ubuntu, not under Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I found this page that finally puts the question to rest. It's at:

[PowerPCFAQ - Ubuntu Wiki#What_software_is_available_for_PowerPC.3F](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#What_software_is_available_for_PowerPC.3F)

and it clearly says that there is no Skype for Ubuntu PowerPC.

Answer (score 0):

Skype is a proprietary application and they do not offer PowerPC builds. If it is possible for you to run the i386 build, it is available in the partner PPA.

Comment: What about that static tar.gz package that they have, would that work if installed manually?

Comment: Or would they have an older version that works on PowerPC?

Comment: It will work if you have a working i386 VM to run it under. As far as I know, Skype has never provided a PowerPC build for Linux.